# Filtering out color

Tags: filter

I have a WWII letter my father wrote that was censured with what looks like a green pen making circular squiggles. Will Photoshop be able to filter out the green and leave the blue writing underneath so I can read it?

Comment: It very much depends on what you have. Could you post an example image? No need for the whole letter, just a word or two would be OK.

Answer (score 2):

Photoshop can filter out the green. But that won't bring the Blue back. If the Blue is completely covered by Green you will basically be left with whatever Green you are already able to see. Maybe by zooming in and really studying minor differences you can get a little bit more out of by scanning but not much. This is also not something a beginner will probably be able to do.

You might be better off bringing it to some sort of historian expert that could look under a microscope to try and find minor differences in the color, but even that will be exceptionally hard.

- So can Photoshop filter out the green? Yes! I still stand by that
- Will it make something directly under the green visible again? Doubtful

Comment: I think you'd need to see the image before saying what Photoshop can or can't do. If all you have is a scanned image with none of the blue information intact then Photoshop isn't going to be able to do much.

Comment: I said in Theory and depending on the image will determine how easy it'll be. No matter how complex the image is, Photoshop can do it, it'll just take more work and know-how @Cai

Comment: Doesn't matter how much work or know-how you put in, If the information isn't there then there's nothing you can do.

Comment: @Cai the person says they have "green circles going over blue writing. Can I remove the green circles leaving the blue writing." The answer to that question is "In theory, and most likely, yes." --- not sure where you're getting this missing information from. It seems like you're just applying What-If Scenarios to it.

Comment: @Ryan If id have to guess the green is some non opaque paint

Comment: @joojaa whats your point?

Comment: Nowhere in the question does it say you can see the blue through the green. It's censured, if the blue was still visible it would be pretty pointless censuring. If I take a picture of my wall can Photoshop tell me what color it was before I painted over it?

Comment: Okay, so it's a letter my father wrote in blue ink and then green ink circles were put over the writing. It's not a scanned copy but the original letter. I can make out that there is writing underneath, but can't read any of it. Photoshop is expensive and I don't want to invest unless there's a pretty good chance it might work. I realize it might not, but just want to know if it's possible.

Comment: Any ideas on how to make the best scanned copy to make it work? Or do I scan it right into photoshop? I've never worked with the program before.

Comment: Also to answer Cai's response, yes I can see that there is writing underneath. I just can't read it though the green circles. So the green isn't covering all the writing, just making it impossible to read.

Comment: @JHall ah now I see. Yes you can remove the green but the blue that isn't already visible will be very difficult to recover. You might be able to recover a bit more using Photoshop but it'll be very hard and certainly not something someone with no photoshop experience can do. So "Can I filter the green?" - yes! "Can I recover the blue ink from directly below it?" - much less likely.

Comment: @Cai ah now I see. I stand by my answer in terms of being able to filter out the green, but no it won't magically make writing completely covered readable unless there's some slight difference that can be found in the color ^

Comment: Thanks Ryan, actually all I want to do is be able to read it if possible. I am typing them up, adding history about where his ship was stationed during the war and creating a bound book to pass down to his children and grandchildren. I think I'll try it and might be back with more questions as I work with the program. You have all been a great help!!!

Comment: @JHall if you're worried about cost you can use the free trial of Photoshop for a month and there are free alternatives that can probably get you the same results

Comment: @JHall I would start by scanning it in at the highest resolution you can without Photoshop and then come into our chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot and we might be able to see what photoshop can do for it

Comment: I have downloaded Gimp 2.8. So far I've tried filters out green, but am not getting much contrast. I'm not sure I'm using the software correctly. Don't know if the colors of the ink are too similar or if there is not enough of the original blue color to come through. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Also I wasn't sure how to scan it so it put it in PDF as most of my scans go into. If I need save the scan differently, please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop can do a lot, if there is a tiny difference of colour, then yes, it can be filtered out (even if not possible to see with the eyes). So give it a shot, make a good picture of it and play around with the curves and similar stuff (Image -> Adjustments -> Curves)

If you want I can do it for you, because Photoshop is indeed expensive. If you'd rather keep the information to yourself I suggest using Gimp, one of the best free photoediting softwares out there. Gimp has enough tools to do the job!